# How do sites make near instant saves into their databases without load times for the users?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

I am working at an app similar to https://trello.com/b/1pVMpFHT/projectcards using Spring Boot and Javascript. The site allows the user to add tasks in different lists. When you press add task, the task is immediately added on the client's screen and saved to their DB without seeing a load time.

In my app, and most of my apps I have ever developed, the flow I use is something like this: client adds something -> send request to the server to add that something in the db -> await on the client until the add is done -> after the add process is done, query the DB for the newest data(if I added a module into an array of modules, I want to return the new array back to the client) -> after the client fetches the newest changes, display them on the screen.(like adding or updating a product in a store and displaying the new changes).

The difference is that in my site, the client has to wait a few seconds before the new data gets displayed after adding something new to it. In most sites I have seen online, there is no wait time.

How do they achieve speeds like that? Is their DB that fast? Are they using some techniques I am not aware of? The problem appears for things like: adding a new tag for a product in a store. Small stuff like this which I feel should not require a load time based on what I have seen on other sites as well.

Comment: Just fake it - right when you add something, immediately show it to the client, save it and update the ID's behind the scenes.

Comment: I have thought about that too. The problem is...what if the DB does not add the new something? Maybe some data is not good, or worse, a small hiccup happens and that something is not added to the DB but exists on the client. I am not sure how I would handle that.

Comment: Typically if a crucial operation fails - we like to pop an error toast message letting the user know - something simple.. "Unable to save changes, please try again", etc etc since most likely the failure is some kind of system outage, not malformed data. If there's a chance for malformed data, get more specific with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question. Your right that old sites would take a users action, run a process to call the server, process the action, return a response back to the browser or client, where the screen would update.

A better way of doing this is to do more work on the client.

When a button is clicked to carry out an action:

1. Process the action (add new item)
2. Add the new item to your DOM say a task on the screen
3. In the background call the server and create the object server side.
4. If the server needs to return an ID for the new item, append that ID to your client side object or dom you created in (2).

The above is very simplistic.

In reality a modern approach to creating web-app would be as follows:

1. Create JSON objects of your artefacts (to-do list)
2. Use a template engine on the client to render the DOM from the JSON.
3. Make server calls in the background, with checks for if the client has lost a connection
4. Consider using local storage for keeping track of changes that need pushing to the server.
5. Create new objects on the client, render the DOM, call the server.
6. Consider if the sever creates the UUID's of new objects, or you can do this on your client.

In reality the process is not much different to how you do things now, it is just a magicians trick to make the user think its fast, when the slow stuff is done behind the scenes so the user can not see it.

Comment: Absolutely. You do not need a framework, however depending on your use case that might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you work on approaches to scale your application horizontally and/or vertically. But if you don't want that and still want to improve your user experience you can try an approach called **optimistic UI**, or **latency compensation**, where you simply assume that the request has resulted in success, and update your UI, so your user doesn't have to wait for the request to finish. This is great because it makes your application looks like it has no response time at all. However, you must always keep in mind that you must rollback the UI changes in case your request actually fails, and also must be able to predict the success response from your server.

Here are two frameworks I've used that have this capability

- [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/performance/optimistic-ui/)
- [Meteor](https://blog.meteor.com/optimistic-ui-with-meteor-67b5a78c3fcf)